# WM and C#: How to set up a WiFi Ad-Hoc connection programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, windows-mobile, wifi

I am trying to build a **Walkie Talkie** application for a **Windows Mobile 6** phone in **C#** using the **.NET Compact Framework**.

How to set up an **Ad-Hoc WiFi** Connection programmatically? What **API**s to use?

Comment: Sounds like a cool application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This other question may be helpful to you.

[Configure Wifi Settings using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469113/configure-wifi-settings-using-c)

Comment: I am aware of that question, but it didn't help me. Thank you.

Comment: That question seems pretty helpful.  What are you missing from it?